# Does RuntimeApis storage accesses counts towards PoV when called from RPC and not any extrinisc?

Tags: custom-rpc, runtime-api, pov

We have some custom RPCs that call some custom RuntimeApis that from inside our pallets  expose some on chain data.

I know that any access (read or write) of on-chain storage from extrinsics will count towards PoV size of the block. My question is if these calls coming from RPCs to only view the data are also counts towards PoV or not.

Data query flow:

```
Custom Rpc -> Custom RunTimeApi -> Pallet -> OnChain Data

Custom Rpc <- Custom RunTimeApi <- Pallet <- OnChain Data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The storage proof (which is part of the Pov) is only collected while building a block. Each storage read that happens in this process is going into the storage proof.

When you are doing RPC calls, these are offchain calls which don't happen as part of the block building. So, they don't increase the PoV.

Answer (score 3):

The PoV is given to the validator for it to be able to execute the state transition function and calculate the new state root (new state). This is to verify the collators have done their work correctly.

A query for on-chain data is handled by the collators and are not verified by validators. Therefore, it is not required in the PoV and will not increase the PoV size.